# Does $a\mid b$ in a Euclidean domain imply $\operatorname{Norm}(b) \ge \operatorname{Norm}(a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the following proposition true?

Let $R$ be a Euclidean Domain, $a,b\in R$, $b\ne 0$, $a|b$. Then $N(b)\ge N(a)$.

I cannot (in my very limited knowledge) think of any counterexamples, but I haven't     managed to come up with a proof, either.

EDIT: In response to comments, here's the definition I'm working with. (This is from Dummit and Foote Chapter 8.)

$N(0) = 0$, $N(r) \ge 0$, and if $a, b\in R$, $b \ne 0$, then there are $q, r \in R$ such that $a = bq + r$ and either $r = 0$ or $N(r) < N(b)$.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you define Euclidean domains. The  property  $\rm N(a) \le N(ab)$  needn't be assumed in order
to deduce all of the basic properties of Euclidean domains. It is true
that any Euclidean function [can be normalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030111/242) to satisfy said property
by defining  $\rm\:\bar N(a) = min\: N(aR^*),\,\ R^* = R\backslash0.\:$

Compare also the analogous [Dedekind-Hasse criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221700/242) for a PID.
You may also find of interest the following paper, which gives an *in-depth* study and comparison of a dozen different definitions / axioms for Euclidean *rings.*

[1] [Euclidean Rings.](http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-95-19-3/pp-291-299.pdf) A. G. Agargun, C. R. Fletcher
Tr. J. of Mathematics, 19, 1995, 291 - 299.

Comment: I see. So if it is not given as part of the definition, it may not be true, but one can always define a new version of the norm that does increase on multiplication. And presumably still has the defining characteristics D&F give... I guess I need to think a little about why the division algorithm is still guaranteed to reduce the new norm.

Comment: @Leon Right. The linked paper is very helpful in understanding the relationships between various definitions.