# Why is $v(a) \leq v(ab)$ superfluous in Euclidean domain definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, euclidean-domain

Can anyone make me understand in simple language why the second condition for being an Euclidean domain is superfluous ?

Why $v(a)  \leq v(ab)$ is not needed?  How we can deduce from the first one?

Comment: [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition).

Comment: It would be good if you could elaborate exactly which part of the construction you find to be "not comprehensible".

Comment: How the new function satisfies the division algorithm?@MisterRiemann

Comment: I'm not really an algebraist, so I'm learning this as we speak. Here is [another reference](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf), which seems to a bit more in-depth about this. (In particular, see Theorem 2.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $V$ satisfies only the first Euclidean property, i.e. for all $\,a,b\in D\,$ if $\,b\neq 0\,$ then there are $\,q,r\in D\,$ such that $\, a = qb +r\,$ with $\, V(r) < V(b),\,$ where $V$ maps $D$ into  (well-ordered)  $\,\Bbb N.\,$ We show how to construct from $V$ another Euclidean function $\,v\,$ satisfying $\, v(a) \le v(ab)\,$ if $\,ab\neq 0$.

Derive $\,v\,$ from $\,V\,$ as follows $$\begin{align} 
v(0) &= V(0)\\
v(a) &= {\rm min}\{ V(b)\ :\ b\in aD\backslash 0\}
\end{align}$$

Note $\,v(a)\le V(a)\,$ since it is clear if $\,a = 0,\,$ else  it follows by $\, a\in aD\backslash 0$.

$v\,$ is also a Euclidean function: if $\,a,b\in D\,$ and $\,b\neq 0\,$ then $\,v(b) = V(bc)\,$ for $\,0\neq c\in D.\,$  Since $\,V\,$ is a Euclidean function there are $\,q,r\in D\,$ such that $\, a = qbc + r\,$ and $\,V(r) < V(bc) = v(b).\,$ But by above we know $\,v(r)\le V(r)\,$ thus $\,v(r) < v(b),\,$ so $\,v\,$ is a Euclidean function.

Note $\, v(a) \le v(ab)\,$ if $\,ab\neq 0\,$ since $\,aD\backslash 0\supseteq abD\backslash 0$ $\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm min}\,V(aD\backslash 0) \le {\rm min}\,  V(abD\backslash 0)$.

**Remark** $ $ See the paper cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143127/242) by Agargun & Fletcher for a comprehensive study of the logical relationships between various common definitions of Euclidean domains and rings.

Comment: More generally see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/264400/6716).

Answer (score -1):

The second property is superfluous because only the first one is needed to prove that every ideal of a Euclidean domain is principal.