# Is it true that $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$ for an Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

Background:

**Exercise:**

If $R$ is a Euclidean domain, is it true that $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$ for all nonzero $a,b\in R?$

**Questions:**

For the above exercise, I don't think the question is an affirmative yes.  For the ring of Gaussian integers, yes.  But what if I am given a constant function for a Euclidean domain $R$ defined as $f(a)=k$ for some nonzero constant $k\in R$ and for all $a\in R,$

Then for any $x,y$ nonzero in $R,$ $f(xy)=k$, but $f(x)f(y)=k^2,$ hence $f(xy)\neq f(a)f(b).$  Am I correct in my guess?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is $\delta$ ?

Comment: Seconding the query from @Digitallis. If it stands for the function we need to drive Euclid's algorithm, then the obvious counterexample is the degree of a polynomial, when we have $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)+\delta(b)$ instead.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ok ok, so it is not universsally true.  Thank you for confirming my suspicious.

Comment: @Digitallis $\delta$ is the function defined in the definition of Euclidean domain.  Sory, I should have been more clear in my post.

Comment: Note  that [we *can* normalize](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030111/242) any Euclidean function to a "least" version satisfying $\,\delta (ab)\ge \delta(a)\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque what does the term "normaliize" mean, and is it standard terminology?  I look at your answer at the other post, I don't see the word being defined?

Comment: For this purpose just think of it as meaning transforming it to satisfy a property we normally encounter in familiar Euclidean domains. Please delete your duplicate comment on the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This fails even for well-known Euclidean functions such as the degree in a polynomial ring. More generally we can define a new Euclidean function by changing the value of $\,\delta\,$ at some point to any *greater* value, making it trivial to destroy this $\delta$'s multiplicative property. Obviously the same method works to twiddle Euclidean functions to destroy many other properties they may possess.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "making it trivial to destroy"?

Comment: @Seth e.g.  in $\Bbb Z$ change the value of $\,\delta(n) = |n|\,$  at $\,n=2\,$ so that $\,\bar\delta(2)>\delta(2) = 2,\,$ e.g. put $\,\bar\delta(2) = 3.\,$ Then $\,4 = \bar \delta (4) \neq \bar\delta(2)^2 = 9,\,$  which destroys the multiplicative property of $\,\delta(n) = |n|.\ \ $