# Definition of Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition, euclidean-domain

Today we learned about Euclidean domains in class but I don't understand why we need one of the conditions stated in the definition. We called an integral domain $R$ a *Euclidean domain* if there exists a function $f$ from $R$ to strictly positive integers such that:

1) For $a,b$ non zero in $R$, $f(ab)\ge f(a)$.

2) If $a,b\in R$, $b\neq 0$, then we can write $a=bq+r$ with $q,r\in R$ such that either $r=0$ or $f(r)<f(b)$.

So from what I understand the whole point of a Euclidean domain is to be able to define a Euclidean algorithm, but I don't see why (1) is needed.
Furthermore later in the class we proved a Euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain and in the proof we didn't use the property (1), so my question is:

> Why do we need (1) in the definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Post in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition) says that the condition 1) is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks! good to clarify that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  property  $\rm\,f(ab)\ge f(a)\,$  need not be assumed in order
to deduce all of the basic properties of Euclidean domains. In fact, any Euclidean function [can be normalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030111/242) to satisfy said property
by defining  $\rm\:\bar f(a)\, =\, min\: f(aR^*),\ R^* = R\backslash0.\:$

Compare also the analogous [Dedekind-Hasse criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221676/can-we-do-long-division-in-mathbb-z-sqrt-n-where-n-is-square-free/221700#221700) for a PID.
$ $And be sure to see [this paper[1],](https://web.archive.org/web/20200605172616/http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr:80/math/issues/mat-95-19-3/pp-291-299.pdf)  an *in-depth* study and comparison of a dozen different definitions/axioms for Euclidean *rings.*

[1] [Euclidean Rings.](https://web.archive.org/web/20200605172616/http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr:80/math/issues/mat-95-19-3/pp-291-299.pdf) A. G. Agargun, C. R. Fletcher
Tr. J. of Mathematics, 19, 1995, 291 - 299.

Comment: Reference to Agargun's paper -- Euclidean Rings is really good

Comment: Hello, do you know where can one find the paper of Agargun and Fletcher now? The original page seems to be missing…

Comment: @CensiLI It's still available at archive.org. I updated the link.

Comment: got it, thanks!