# Why must a Euclidean function map to $\mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, euclidean-algorithm, euclidean-domain

I'm not sure I get the motivation for a Euclidean function having to map to $\mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$. E.g. it would seem that $\mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ would be a natural choice for a ring of "polynomials" permitting positive real exponents (e.g. $x^{2.5}+x^{0.5}+1$) -- and you can do long division on them too.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The codomain can be any *well-ordered* set (so that Euclidean descent *terminates*). See the paper of Agargun and Fletcher [cited here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1156449/242) on relationships between variations on the definition of Euclidean rings.

Comment: And thus by the well-ordering theorem, we can take $\mathbb{R}$ to be the codomain ;)

Comment: Hello, do you know where can one find the paper of Agargun and Fletcher now? The original page seems to be missing…