# Integral multiple Lcm proof

Tags: number-theory

[image][image]

I am trying to figure out what my next step would be in this problem. What can I say about e in relation to m and n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ By definition  $\,\overbrace{J_a\cap J_b =\, J_{\ell}}^{\textstyle a\Bbb Z\cap b\Bbb Z = \ell \Bbb Z},\ \ell = {\rm lcm}(a,b),\,$ is equivalent to

**Theorem** $\,\ a,b\mid m\iff {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid m\quad$ **[Universal Property of LCM]**

**Proof** $\ $  $(\Leftarrow)$ by definition of lcm and transitivity of divisibility: $\ a,b\mid {\rm lcm}(a,b)\mid m\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,a,b\mid m.$
$(\Rightarrow)$ may be conceptually proved by *Euclidean descent* as below.

The set $M$ of all positive common multiples of all $\,a,b\,$ is *closed under positive subtraction,* i.e. $\,m> n\in M$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,a,b\mid m,n\,\Rightarrow\, a,b\mid m\!-\!n\,\Rightarrow\,m\!-\!n\in M.\,$ Therefore, by induction, we deduce that $\,M\,$ is also *closed under mod, i.e. remainder,* since it arises by repeated subtraction, i.e. $\ m\ {\rm mod}\ n\, =\, m-qn = ((m-n)-n)-\cdots-n.\,$ Thus the least $\,\ell\in M\,$ divides every  $\,m\in M,\,$ else $\ 0\ne m\ {\rm mod}\ \ell\ $ lies in $\,M\,$ and is smaller than $\,\ell,\,$ contra minimality of $\,\ell.$

**Remark** $ $ The above means  lcm is a *divisibility*-least common multiple, i.e. it is least in the divisibility order $\, a\prec b\!\! \overset{\rm def}\iff\! a\mid b.\ $ This is the (universal) definition of lcm used in general rings (which  generally - not being [Euclidean (or PID)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221700/242) -  lack that way to measure "least"). [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242) for more on the general viewpoint.

Comment: Thank you. Did you mean Jm $\cap$ Jn though? I will read through this.

Comment: @Math4Life Yes, the cup in now a cap.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $m | e$ and $n | e$. By definition of $\operatorname{lcm}$, we have that since $e$ is a multiple of $m$ and $n$, it is also a multiple of their lcm. Hence. $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n) | e$, so it follows that $e \in J_{\operatorname{lcm}(m,n) }$.

The other direction is obvious: If something is a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm(m,n)}$, then it is naturally a multiple of $m$ and $n$.