# Proving if $d_0$ is the smallest positive integer in $S$ then $d_0 = \gcd(a,b)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would appreciate hints to this. I've done part (a) but am unconfident.
Wondering how I could approach part (b)

**Question's comment**
-- The aim of this question is to use the Division Algorithm and the definition of greatest common divisor (gcd) to show that $d_0 = \gcd(a,b)$.

### Question:

Let $a,b$ be integers, not both zero, let $S$ be the set of integers defined by
$$S = \{ ax + by | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
and let $d_0$ be the smallest positive integer in the set $S$.
Prove:
a. If $s\in S$, then $d_0$ is a divisor of $s$.
b. $d_0$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$.
c. If $d$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$, then $d$ is a divisor of $d_0$.
d. $d_0 =\gcd(a,b),$ and hence there exists integers $x,y$ such that $ax + by = \gcd(a,b)$.

### Attempt:

Note I don't expect full (or any hints to the problem(s) as there are quite a bit, but I would just appreciate hints.
a. Let $s \in S$. Then $s = d_0 q + r$ for some $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$.
By definition, $d_0 = ax_0 + by_0$ for some $x_0,y_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.
$s = ax_s + by_s$ for some $x_s,y_s \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Hence, $$ax_s + by_s = q(ax_0 + by_0) + r\\
a(x_s - qx_0) + b(y_s - qy_0) = r.$$
Define $x_r:= x_s - qx_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y_r:= y_s - qy_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Then this shows that $r \in S$ which implies $d_0 | s$.

Comment: Hint  : Bézout's identity

Comment: I believe that's what we're trying to prove in part (d).

Comment: This is correct, but has one drawback, in my opinion: it relies on *Euclidean division*. However the same result is true even for P.I.D.s which have no Euclidean division algorithm, and it can be proved in a very simple way, using the *minimality* of $d_0$.

Comment: Note that you also need to prove that $d_0$ is well-defined, i.e. that $S$ has at least one positive element. The PID case mentioned by @Bernard is known as the Dedekind-Hasse PID test,
 e.g. see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221700/242)

Answer (score 2):

a. I'm not quite sure how you can just conclude from $r\in S$ that $d_0|s$ holds. But you can easily do it. Due to the euclidean division you get either $r=0$, which would imply $d_0|s$, or $0<r<d_0$, which is a contradiction to the minimality of $d_0$.

b. Use the last statement and $a,b\in S$.

c. Because $d_0\in S$ there exist integers $x,y$ with $d_0=ax+by$. So if $d|a,b$, then also $d|ax+by=d_0.$

d. We already showed $d_0|a,b$, which impliess $d_0|gcd(a,b)$, by the definition of the gcd. But $gcd(a,b)|a,b$, which impliess using c. that $gcd(a,b)|d_0$. So we have two positive numbers and each divides the other one, meaning they are equal, i.e. $d_0=gcd(a,b).$

Comment: +1 ... I was in the middle of typing a more extended answer, but you was faster! Well done ;)

Comment: Thanks. For d. Why does $d_0|a,b$ imply $d_0|\gcd(a,b)$?  
I'm not sure what definition is used, (or how to prove that).

Comment: Because every number which divides two numbers also divides their gcd. If that is not entirely clear write $a=\prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i}$ and $b=\prod_i p_i^{\beta_i}$. Then every divisor $d=\prod_i p_i^{\gamma_i}$ must satisfy $\gamma_i\leq \min\{\alpha_i,\beta_i\}$ and for the gcd equality is attained for all $i.$

Answer (score 0):

**a** Your proof is correct, but incomplete. When [applying Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), $0 \leq r < d_0$. You show that $r \in S$, is positive and smaller than $d_0$ (which is smallest by definition) thus a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I can't see why applying Euclidean division would show that $0 \leq r\leq d_0$.

Comment: When $s=d_0q+r$, you are applying Euclidean division, which is a theorem, which states that $0\leq r < |d_0|$. But $d_0$ is positive, thus according to Euclidean division $0\leq r < d_0$.

Comment: $q$ should also be positive right by definition (or convention)?

Comment: Not necessarily,  Euclidean division states nothing about $q$ (apart from it's unique) and it can't since, particularly for this case, $s \in S$ can also be negative. From $s=d_0q+r < 0$ we will deduct that $q <0$ since everything else ($d_0,r$) is positive. But this doesn't matter, since you show that $r \in S$ too.

Comment: There are no restrictions on the sign of $q.$

Answer (score 0):

$(a)\ $ $\,d_0\nmid s\,$ $\,\Rightarrow\, 0 <  s\bmod d_0 < d_0\,$ is a smaller positive element of $S$, contra minimality of $d_0\,$ (notice  $\,s\bmod d_0 = s - k\, d_0\,$ for some integer $k\,$ so it lies in $S,\,$ i.e. $S$ is $\rm\color{#0a0}{closed\  under\ mod}$).

$(b)\ $ Applying prior to $\,s = a,b\in S\,$ yields $\,d_0\mid a,b,\,$ i.e. $\,d_0$ is a *common divisor* of $\,a,b$

$(c)\ \ d_0\in S\,\Rightarrow\, d_0 = \color{#c00}aj+\color{#c00}bk\,$  so $\,d\mid \color{#c00}{a,b}\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid d_0$

$(d)\  \ d_0\,$ is a common divisor of $\,a,b$ by $(b),\,$ necessarily the *greatest* common divisor since by $(c),\,$ $\,d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid d_0\,\Rightarrow\, d\le d_0.\,$ Therefore, by definition, $\,d_0 = \gcd(a,b).\,$ Furthermore, we deduce  from $\,d_0\in S\,$ said Bezout linear representation $\,\gcd(a,b) = ax+by.$

**Remark** $\ $ Said more concisely $\, a\Bbb Z + b\Bbb Z = d_0\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, d_0 = \gcd(a,b).\,$ This viewpoint is clarified when one learns ideal theory. But one can understand this more *conceptual* viewpoint even without knowledge of ideals (or groups), see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242) (which greatly clarifies the essence of the matter).