# Is there a way to check in general that a ring is not an EUD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question

**Question:** Is there an easy way to check that an integral domain is *not* an EUD?

I know that we have the implication that if $R$ is an EUD it is a PID, so if we can show $R$ is not a PID then it is not an EUD. This seems like the simplest way to check if something is not an EUD, find an ideal which isn't generated by a single element. But because all we need for an integral domain to be an EUD is a norm function, is there in general no easy way to show that no such norm function exists?

Comment: No, there is no easy way in general, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246049/how-do-i-prove-whether-something-is-a-euclidean-domain) and its answers: "To my knowledge, given an arbitrary integral domain, there is no "general" method to figure out whether it is a Euclidean domain or not."