# A principal ideal domain that is not a Euclidean domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Somebody can to help me in the following problem:

> Let R be the following subring of the complex numbers: $$R = \left\{\frac{z_1}{2}+\frac{z_2\sqrt{-19}}{2} : z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{Z}, \;\text{with the same parity}\right\}.$$
>   Then R is a principal ideal domain that is not a Euclidean domain.

Note: A ring for me is commutative and with identity.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23844/78535)

Comment: What *is* the question here? This statement is true.

Comment: There is a general problem with asserting that an algebraically-closed ring of algebraic integers is a PID but not Euclidean, unless the notion of "Euclidean" is constrained to mean something like "with the usual norm". Namely, I seem to recall that under GRH or similar every such ring that is a PID has _some_ "norm" that makes it Euclidean. So please do append "not Euclidean with respect to its usual norm", or some similar. Otherwise the question is too hard.

Comment: I don't get to do this exercise. Do you can to help me?

Comment: This is a problem of introductory book in abstract algebra. I think that this is only a little trick that I don't know.

Comment: @paulgarrett Thee is no such problem here - see the proof I linked to, by H. Lenstra, which uses the *universal side divisor criterion* to deduce that no Euclidean function exists. This does not contradict Weinberger's 1973 result (assuming GRH) since that applies only to number rings with infinitely many units.

Comment: @KeyIdeas, Ah, indeed, good.

Comment: Guys, I see that somebody already ask this question. But this don't mean that I don't have doubts. If somebody can to help me, is it wellcome.