# $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ is PID

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am reading Dummit & Foote's book and on page 282, I can't understand the part that I have offset and bolded in the following quote. How can we conclude that $ay-19bx=cq+r$? I know that there is different proof for the same question but I am curious to understand the proof of Dummit & Foote's book.

> **Example**
>
> Let $R = \mathbb{Z}\left [(1 + \sqrt{-19})/2 \right ]$ be the quadratic integer ring considered at the end of the previous section. we show that the positive field norm $N(a + b(1 + \sqrt{-19})/2) = a^2 + ab + 5b^2$ defined on $R$ is a Dedekind-Hasse norm, which by Proposition 9 and the results of the previous section will prove that $R$ is a P.I.D. but not a Euclidean Domain.
>
> Suppose $\alpha, \beta$ are nonzero elements of $R$ and $\alpha/\beta \not \in R$. We must show that there are elements $s,t \in R$ with $0 < N(s \alpha - t \beta) < N(\beta)$, which by the multiplicativity of the field norm is equivalent to
>
> $$ 0 < N \left ( \frac{\alpha}{\beta} s - t \right ) < 1. \quad \quad (*)$$
>
> Write $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \frac{a + b \sqrt{-19}}{c} \in \mathbb{Q} \left [ \sqrt{-19} \right ]$ with integers $a,b,c$ having no common divisor and with $c > 1$ (since $\beta$ is assumed not to divide $\alpha$). Since $a,b,c$ have no common divisor there are integers $x,y,z$ with $ax + by + cz = 1$.
>
> **Write $ay - 19bx = cq + r$ for some quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ with $|r| \leq c/2$ and let $s = y + x \sqrt{-19}$ and $t = q - z \sqrt{-19}$**.
>
> Then a quick computation shows that
>
> $$0 < N \left ( \frac{\alpha}{\beta} s - t \right ) = \frac{(ay - 19bx - cq)^2 + 19 (ax + by + cz)^2}{c^2} \leq \frac{1}{4} + \frac{19}{c^2}$$
>
> and so $(*)$ is satisfied with this $s$ and $t$ provided $c \geq 5$.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searcahble) rather than an image (which isn't) so that other users will have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: All they are doing is applying the division algorithm. Divide $ay-19bx$ by $c$ to get a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$. If $r$ is larger than $|c|/2$, then replace it with $r-c$ and replace $q$ with $q+1$.

Comment: As in the dupe they choose the unique remainder $r$  in a balanced (signed) residue system $\!\bmod c,\,$ which is a complete system of residues $\!\bmod c\ \  $

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23872/242).

Answer (score 1):

$ay - 19bx$ is some integer. Now we can use the [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) to write $ay - 19bx = qc + r$.

Typically we assume the remainder $r$ lies in $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, c-1\}$, but we don't have to. We can take the remainder to land in *any* consecutive run of $c$ numbers. For instance, we can choose $\{-(c-1)/2, \ldots, -1, 0, 1, \ldots, (c-1)/2 \}$ (with an obvious modification if $c$ is even). As an example, instead of writing

$$17 = 5 \cdot 3 + 2$$

we could write

$$17 = 6 \cdot 3 - 1$$

If we do this, instead of knowing $0 \leq r < c$, we learn that $|r| \leq c/2$, as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the thing that I couldn't understand is, why did he consider $ay-19bx$? I can't understand the idea of considering this specific element!!!

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque -- I'm normally pretty good about checking approach0, but I didn't on this one. Thanks for catching the dupe ^_^

Comment: @Babak The reason *why* is that they are essentially using a generalization of the division algorithm that goes back to Hurwitz, e.g. see Lemmermeyer's [An application of the Dedekind-Hasse criterion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1147.pdf) and Fendel [Prime-Producing Polynomials and Principal Ideal Domains](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/undergradsem2020/Fendel.pdf)