# Why Hurwitz 's lemma is called as a weak generalization of the Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Why Hurwitz's lemma(Hurwitz's lemma says that there exists a positive integer M with the following properties that for a,b(nonzero)belongs to ring of integers there is a t, 1<=t<=M & w belongs to ring of integers such that |N(at-bw)|<|N(b)|)is called as a weak generalization of the Euclidean Algorithm? Can some one give an example where Euclidean Algorithm fails true but this lemma holds true?
I'm thinking about in Z[√-5] can you elaborate give me an answer in this ring of integers? It's an important question from Ireland & rosen book " A Classical Introduction to Modern Number theory".

Comment: Can you please expand your post to make it understandable, and add some context? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: See e.g. the papers by Lemmermeyer and Fendel that I cite in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661955/mathbbz1-sqrt-19-2-is-pid#comment9848642_4661964)